# TypeError: no implicit conversion of false into Hash

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, yaml

I am learning ruby and fairly new to coding in it. Below is the chef recipe that I wrote to merge two hashes and write to YAML file.

```
 yaml_string = "AVG_METRICS: 
 get_requests:
 - OneMinuteRate
 - FifteenMinuteRate"

 trimmed_custom_hash = YAML.load(yaml_string)
 ruby_block do
     merger = proc do |key,v1,v2|
          Hash === v1 && Hash === v2 ? v1.merge(v2, &merger) : v2
     end
     block do
         if test_string.start_with? "7."
            default_hash = YAML.load_file(File.join('/opt/tests/metrics','metrics_test.yml'))
            default_hash.merge!(trimmed_custom_hash, &merger)
            File.open("/opt/tests/metrics/metrics_test.yml", "w") { |file| file.write(default_hash.to_yaml)}
         end
    end
end
```

I am unable to understand why the implicit conversion error occurs. I have come up with questions when considering possibilities of where it might be failing.

1. What would be the return value of this block?
2. If an if condition has "?", then is the block supposed to return only true or false?
3. Are there any points that I need to remember when using ruby_block in chef?

I have been trying to figure this out for a while. It would be great if you could point me to where the error might be. Thanks!

Comment: `default_hash.merge!` is apparently calling `merge!` on a `File`. That seems unlikely to work.

Comment: Sorry @matthewd. Updated the code with right method. YAML.load_file has return value as hash.

Comment: "It would be great if you could point me to where the error might be." – The error message will tell you exactly were the error occurs. Since you don't tell us that information, it is hard to near impossible to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An error like this is raised when `merge` is called on a hash with `false` as an argument:

```
{}.merge(false)
#=> TypeError (no implicit conversion of false into Hash)
```

I would expect the error to be in the line `v1.merge(v2, &merger)` or in `default_hash.merge!(trimmed_custom_hash, &merger)`. Why does it happen? Hard to tell without knowing how `trimmed_custom_hash` is defined.

It is a common Ruby idiom that methods ending with an `?` should return a boolean. But I would rely on this because it is just a convention and it isn't enforced by the language itself.

Comment: Hi @spickermann. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I am using YAML.load method to convert string to hash. Do you think that method might be the reason for this issue? If yaml_string is empty, how does YAML.load behave? Thanks again!

Comment: `YAML.parse("") #=> false`

Comment: Checking if trimmed_custom_yaml is a hash solved my problem. Thanks @spickermann